# Using a callback in a model that modifies the column of another model (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called **Vote** and this is what **vote.rb** looks like:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :update_total

  protected

  def update_total
    self.total ||= 0
    self.total += self.polarity
  end
end
```

(it is polymorphic because it also belongs to another model called **Comment**).

Each time a vote is created the value of total is updated. For example, `Vote.create(:polarity => 2)`, will produce `:polarity => 2, :total => 2`

I just realize that this doesn't make sense because `:polarity` will always equal to `:total`. What I actually want to do is to have the `total` to the model that **Vote** belongs to; in this case **Post** and **Comment** (**Vote** belongs to post and **Post** has many votes) so that each time a vote is created, the `total` column in the post will be updated. Like this:

May 13

```
Post.total = 3 (:id => 2)

Vote.polarity = 1 (:id => 1)
Vote.polarity = -1 (:id => 2)
Vote.polarity = 3 (:id => 3)
```

May 14

```
Post.total = 4 (:id => 2)

Vote.polarity = 1 (:id => 1)
Vote.polarity = -1 (:id => 2)
Vote.polarity = 3 (:id => 3)
Vote.polarity = 1 (:id => 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the total of the votable object in this way:

```
def update_total
  if self.votable.class.column_names.include?("total")
    total_average = self.votable.total ||= 0
    self.votable.update_attribute(:total, total_average + self.polarity)
  end
end
```

or you can use the conditional callback like @Sandip says:

```
before_create :update_total, :if => defined_total

def defined_total
  self.votable.class.column_names.include?("total")
end

def update_total
  total_average = self.votable.total ||= 0
  self.votable.update_attribute(:total, total_average + self.polarity)
end
```

Comment: Sorry this may be a stupid question but I have to create the `total` column for both Post and Comment models first right?

Comment: Yes, you need to create the total column for all the votable models you use

Comment: not necessarily u can always check for `total` is defined or not if you specifically need it for only `post` votes.
before_create :update_total, :if => "self.votable.defined?(:total)"

Comment: avoid `total_average = self.votable.total ||= 0` by having default total 0 in migration

Comment: @Sandip Ransing Hey I'm interested in your ideas. Can you write them in an answer?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with the conditional update, like @SandipRansing was saying.

Comment: @Matteo Alessani for some reason `self.votable` is no assigning any values to the `votable` element `total` keepa displaying as `nil`.

Comment: you can try to check if votable_id and votable_type are correctly filled.